# Mod-protection as a precautionary measure

Tags: discussion

Lately, we've had a number of questions show up at the top of the "hot questions" list:

[image]

When this happens, things tend to get [messy](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8930/should-i-recommend-a-student-with-a-bad-ideology). Because of that, I often [protect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/52764/139256) questions that are turning into hot ones. This has [worked well in the past](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/8194/how-to-deal-with-sexual-advances-from-students); the aforelinked question was protected while it appeared in the menu, and the extraneous content was limited.

To that end, I protected the question "[Keeping your throat comfortable after hours of lecturing](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9085/keeping-your-throat-comfortable-after-hours-of-lecturing)". In case you were wondering why, that's why.

Comment: A note: high-rep users can also protect questions… and I strongly agree with you that protecting "hot" questions is a good idea in general

Comment: Thanks, it's definitely a good approach.

Comment: Weird - I thought that was a terrible question **for this site**. Lots of jobs involve long periods of talking. Yet people love the question. (of course, that doesn't necessarily mean it's a good fit for the site.)

Comment: @EnergyNumbers - Funny, I thought it was just fine. You can open another meta question if you wish to discuss it. Even better, [this question](http://meta.academia.stackexchange.com/q/459/73) which was just posted an hour ago is basically on the same topic; feel free to chime in.

Comment: I didn't get "why"...

Answer (score 2):

You might find [this meta.stackexchange post interesting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164080/why-can-only-moderators-protect-questions-less-than-1-day-old).

As someone who is on a site which also gets a lot of questions up there (some of which are of varying quality...) I absolutely err on the side of protecting them as protection against spammy types of answers.

Just a note - high rep users can only protect questions after a few days have passed. Moderators can protect immediately.